# Makefile libtool uninstall - Duplicate `.so` files removed

Tags: libtool

I am trying to write a Makefile with an uninstall option, I'm using

```
install: $(MODULE_NAME).la
    if [ -f $(MODULE_NAME).la ] ; then \
        $(LIBTOOL) --mode=install $(INSTALL_BIN) $(MODULE_NAME).la $(OUTPUTDIR) ; \
    fi

uninstall:
    $(LIBTOOL) --mode=uninstall $(RM) $(OUTPUTDIR)/$(MODULE_NAME).la
```

However, when I try and uninstall (`make uninstall`) it, it gives me :-

`libtool: uninstall: /bin/rm /usr/lib/proftpd/mod_mymod.la /usr/lib/proftpd/mod_mymod.so /usr/lib/proftpd/mod_dhynotify.so /usr/lib/proftpd/mod_mymod.so /usr/lib/proftpd/mod_mymod.a`

Any idea why its generating so many .so file removals?

Comment: Doesn't the same thing happen when you do it by hand? This looks like a libtool question, not a Make question.

Comment: Good point, I've re-tagged as libtool